# set axis limit using Date on x axis python

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, limit, axis-labels

Im having difficulty changing the x axis on my scatter plot

```
events_perday = df[['Dates','Category']].query('Category == "LARCENY/THEFT"').groupby(['Dates']).count()
events_perday = events_perday.resample('D',how=sum)
events_perday.dropna(inplace = True)

N = 2248
colors = np.linspace(0,1,N)
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 14
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 14
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,axisbg='black')
ax.grid(b=False)

#plt.xlim([2003-01-06,'2015-05-13'])
ax.scatter(events_perday.index, events_perday['Category'],c=colors ,cmap = "winter")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY5xJ.png

As you can see I just need to bring it in a little bit but I have been researching and still am stuck at this point :/

Comment: you can decrease your `xaxis` fontsize and add manual `xticks`, i.e. add `2003`